# Not able to read a file that I just created and wrote in

Tags: python

I'm able to read files perfectly fine, the problem comes when I attempt to read a file that I *just* created and wrote on. The output is [] instead of the actual lines I attempted to write into the text file. When the code executes, the file is created with the text written inside, it just isn't being read.

```
FileObject = open('Fileobject.txt', 'x+')
FileObject.write("testing")
print(FileObject.readlines())
FileObject.close()
```

The expected output was "testing", but the actual output I got was [], as if the file that I just created was blank rather than containing text.

I thought that the process would go *Create File > write in file > read the contents written in the file*, but it's completely ignoring the contents I added in the file. Why is that?

Comment: The cursor is at the end of what you've written, there's no file content _after_ that.

Comment: You need `FileObject.seek(0)` before reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `readlines` is called, the current file position is already at the end of the file.  If you want to move it back to the start, you can call `seek`.  For example:

```
FileObject = open('Fileobject.txt', 'x+')
FileObject.write("testing")
FileObject.seek(0)
print(FileObject.readlines())
FileObject.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if this was a basic question, just started learning it today.